# Azure DevOps newly created permission group is not showing up in Repository security assignment

Tags: azure, azure-devops

It's pretty straight forward.

Create the group from permissions in `project settings` -> assign members -> go to the repository and try and add the group. The group doesn't show up nor can you search for it. It's odd because I just did this last week.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Example from [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-devops-setting-up-repository-permissions/#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20Group%20for%20Repository%20Access&text=Under%20the%20project%20settings%2C%20go,then%20click%20on%20%E2%80%9CCreate%E2%80%9D.)

> In this example, I want to set up a repository for read-only access. Instead of working with individual user access, it is best to define a group. Under the project settings, go to Permissions > New Group. Enter the Group Name and add the members. Note: if members do not display in the drop-down list, you must first add them to your organization. Next, enter a group description and then click on “Create”. If you go back into the group you created, you will notice that the group got added to the group “Project, Valid Users”. All groups will be added to this group automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Microsoft and they were helpful on the issue. Basically they were doing maintenance, as I was told, and it started working again after a couple hours.

Not a good user experience because there is no warning or output that you've done anything wrong. It just doesn't work.